# SSRS - How can I set the format for the date/time parameter to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss?

Tags: sql-server, date, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report in SSRS that requires data to be shown between a data range.
One of my datasets works perfectly inside the query designer, but when I run the report, the data returned is blank.

I figured out that this is due to the SSRS date time looking like this:

```
'14/01/2019 10:33:59 AM'
```

My SQL stored procedure that I am using for my dataset requires the following format:

```
2019-01-14 10:33:59
```

How can I make SSRS comply with the format requirement?

Comment: Why not use the `date` datatype for your SP then there will never be any formatting issues.

Comment: https://dattatreysindol.com/2011/02/10/formatting-date-and-time-in-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-reports/

Comment: If you use date or datetime data types throughout (SQL Server and SSIS), you shouldn't have a problem. Introducing date formats (which you suggest in your question) _causes_ issues rather than solves them. Please indicate what data types are used in your stored procedure and what data type your parameters are.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set under report properties, localization your language to a value (this property can´t be empty), then you can add the following expression for your desired output:

```
=Format(CDate("14/01/2019 10:33:59 AM"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

'Result
->2019-01-14 10:33:59
```